# How to define global constants for all tests in a suite?

Tags: java, junit, constants

I would like to have constants which I can access
from every test class in a Suite.

How to define them ?

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    ATest.class,
    BTest.class,
    CTest.class,
})

public class AllTests {
   // define constants
}
```

...

```
public class ATest {
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        // use constant here
    }

}
```

do I need to use inheritance ?

Comment: Pretty generic questions, but anyway. I would recommend to **not** use inheritance here. Whats wrong with using some interface that provides the constants. And what kind of constants do you actually have in mind here? You see, the idea of unit tests is that they should test small units. So, the idea that all unit tests are sharing some piece of information ... smells a bit like "bad design". In other words: why do you want global constants?

Comment: @Jägermeister. All test classes need a certain path where the Object is tested in units